Why does Response.Redirect cause a ThreadAbort error in .NET 4.8?
I'm currently upgrading a VB website from VS 2005 .NET 2.0 to VS 2022 .NET 4.8.
The .NET 2.0 version works fine, but Response.Redirect fails with a ThreadAbortException in .NET 4.8. Why is this happening, and what could I do to fix it?

Are you sure it fails? What HTTP response code does the client get?  The exception might just be to stop further request processing on the server after the redirect.
